# mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given

Tags: php, mysqli

Me sale un error al intentar insertar valores a una tabla
Este es el codigo:

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';

$user = 'root';

$pass = '';

$db = 'cursosudemy';

$nombreTabla = 'infiniterunner';

$conexion = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die('No se pudo conectar');

echo "Conectado con exito a la base de datos"."\n";

mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db) or die('No hemos podido seleccionar la Base de datos');

echo "Base de datos " . $nombreTabla . " seleccionada con exito"."\n";

InsertarElemento($nombreTabla);

function InsertarElemento($nombreTabla)
{

$queryInsert = " INSERT INTO " . $nombreTabla . "" . "(nombre, puntuaciones, lasttime) VALUES ('Juan', '50', '12-12-2015')";

$resultInsert = mysqli_query($nombreTabla, $queryInsert) or die('Fallo al ingresar valores');
echo 'Insertado';
}

?>
```

Comment: No se subio tu codigo

Comment: Porfa, sube el codigo para ver el error

Comment: Tu error radica que en mysqli_query no le estas pasando la cadena de conexion, si no el nombre de la tabla ahi pon tu cadena y deberia de funcionar Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu error es que en tu *mysqli_query* estás pasando como parámetro el nombre de la tabla en vez de la conexión, y para poder usar el de la conexión tienes que pasarle esa variable al hacer el llamado de la función, así:

```
InsertarElemento($conexion, $nombreTabla);
```

Y luego en el *mysqli_query* pones esa variable de conexión:

```
mysqli_query($conexion, $queryInsert)
```

Por lo demás, a mi gusto tienes mucho código innecesario y lo podrías resumir un poco de esta manera:

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'control';
$nombreTabla = 'infiniterunner';

$conexion = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($conexion));

InsertarElemento($conexion, $nombreTabla);

function InsertarElemento($con, $tabla){
    $queryInsert = "INSERT INTO " .$tabla. " (nombre, puntuaciones, lasttime) VALUES ('Juan', '50', '12-12-2015')";
    $resultInsert = mysqli_query($con, $queryInsert) or die('Fallo al ingresar valores');
    echo 'Insertado';
}
?>
```